# How to calculate with reference id

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook in which there is stock detail on sheet 1 and sales detail on sheet 2.

I want to auto-calculate the remaining stock. But the sales inventory is based on dates so all the different products are mixed up. Every product has a unique ID.  So how I can subtract the sale product from stock based on their IDs?

An example:

- The customer comes and buy 4 shirts.
- I enter the product with product ID, and in the Qty column I added 4.
- Now I want to minus 4 from actual stock.

How it can be done in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the sum of all sold products in sheet 2 **based on condition** that productID in sheet2 equals our interesting product in sheet1. Use:

```
=SUMIFS(B2:B100,A2:A100,productID)
```

where column A contains product IDs and column B contains "sold" values.

Then subtract that sum from the stock total in sheet1, e.g:

```
=B3-(SUMIFS(Sheet2!B1:B100;Sheet2!A1:A100;A3))
```

where column A contains product IDs and column B includes stock totals.

(note how "productID" from the first expression is here replaced with "A3", i.e. the **value** of productID column for the current row).

Copying this last formula to other product rows should automatically update the relevant values.